# Resolving Password correctly with @ sign in git

Tags: git, github

I am trying to resolving my username and password correctly, while connecting to a github repository

```
Username : username
Password : password@1234
URL : https://username:password@v1234t@something.github.com:4521/avc/rdf/connect.git/
```

I am not able to connect , and is getting the below error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://username:password@v1234t@something.github.com:4521/avc/rdf/connect.git/': Couldn't resolve host 'v1234t'
```

Is there any way I could resolve my username and password with @ correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use SSH instead of HTTPS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+special+characters+in+url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the ascii character (%40) inplace of @ in passoword

use

```
https://username:password%40v1234t@something.github.com:4521/avc/rdf/connect.git/
```

for the reason see @Dietrich's answer

Answer (score 1):

The URL is invalid… it should probably be rejected outright. You cannot include raw `@` characters in the userinfo portion of a URI.

Replace the `@` with `%40`.